# Error when referencing an attribute of type Map inside a closure

Tags: groovy, closures, compile-static

In the following code segment, why does the compiler complain about the map attribute but not other types of attributes:

```
import groovy.transform.CompileStatic

@CompileStatic
class TestMapInClosure {

    Map amap = [:]
    List alist = []
    Integer intval = 0

    Closure doFoo = {           
        this.amap['one'] = 'two'  // !! [Static type checking] - No such property
        this.alist.push(1)
        this.intval += 5
    }
}
```

`this` inside a closure is supposed to refer to the instance of the enclosing class, if I understand things correctly.

*Note: Groovy Version: 2.4.5*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a bug in the `CompileStatic` annotation, as if you change the line to:

```
this.amap += [one:'two']
```

Or

```
this.amap.one = 'two'
```

Then it works fine.  I'm guessing it's due to the semantics of the `[]` map accessor.

You could [sumbit it as a bug](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/GROOVY/?selectedTab=com.atlassian.jira.jira-projects-plugin:issues-panel) and see if it can be fixed